# SendInput wrong Parameter

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, sendinput

I wanted to improve my `SendInput()` function but came across an error.

> ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER
>
> ```
> 87 (0x57)
>
> The parameter is incorrect.
> ```
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx

I am a bit confused which parameter should not be correct.

If I have forgotten something do not hesitate to ask.

```
INPUT in[6] = {0};

//Press Enter Key
in[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
in[0].ki.wScan = 0;
in[0].ki.dwFlags = 0;
in[0].ki.time = 0;
in[0].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
in[0].ki.wVk = VK_RETURN;

//release enter key
in[1] = in[0];
in[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

//Hold Shift key and press key 7
in[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
in[2].ki.wScan = 0;
in[2].ki.dwFlags = 0;
in[2].ki.time = 0;
in[2].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
in[2].ki.wVk = VK_SHIFT;

in[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
in[3].ki.wScan = 0;
in[3].ki.dwFlags = 0;
in[3].ki.time = 0;
in[3].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
in[3].ki.wVk = 0x37;

//release key 7
in[4] = in[3];
in[4].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

//release key shift
in[5] = in[2];
in[5].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

if (SendInput(6, in, sizeof(in)) == 0)
{
std::cout << "Uppps some error in SendInput: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I know that my english is not the best, although I have tried very hard to make the question clear and will be voted down immediately. I would like to know what it is to make it better next time. thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The size, in bytes, of an INPUT structure. If cbSize is not the size of an INPUT structure, the function fails.

```
SendInput(6, in, sizeof(INPUT));
```

Oups...

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) says of `cbSize`:

> The size, in bytes, of an INPUT structure. If cbSize is not the size of an INPUT structure, the function fails.

You are passing `sizeof(in)`, the size of the entire array. Instead pass `sizeof(INPUT)`.